# How add two views or image views in landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimage

I want to create view in which when user use in portrait mode then two images scroll in scroll view and when user change mode as landscape then both image views add and become single view. I show this function in restoration hardware apps.I like that so i want to make my apps like that? how do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask, is a simple implementation that I could do for you. But then again, you would't learn anything and you would probably come here and ask again. I won't give you the fish, I will show you a way of catching it. Check this tutorial, to learn how to handle rotation and then manipulate your views the way you want:

http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/iphone-auto-rotation-for-intermediate-developers-tutorial-1/

In my profile you have my personal email, after you learn that, if you need more help, count with me.